# How to use setTimeout to monitor the progress of a long running function

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component below. When my user clicks on the click me button,
I want to call a long running transaction with the function GetAllData after 3 seconds.

In the h1 tag, I want to be able to update my users so that they can know when the
long running transaction is done. I will like to count down like 5,4,3,2,1, Done

How can I update this code to do that?

```
        import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

        export default function App() {
          const [count, setCount] = useState(5);

          const kickoff = () => {
            const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
              GetAllData()
              //setCount(1);
            }, 3000);
          
          }
          
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <h1>{count}</h1>
              <button onClick={() => kickoff}>Click Me</button>
            </div>
          );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you countdown a long-running process? Is there any scenario where you know exactly how long it'll take when you call it so you can count backwards to 0? The answer is no.

If you want to notify the users when it's done, use state and set a flag when the process is complete (in callback).

```
const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false)

<h1>{isRunning ? 'Process is running': ''}</h1>
```

### Edit

If it's a long-running process, you may want to spin that off into a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) (you'll have to research that on your own). Or, you could wrap it in a promise.

Basically you'll set the flag to true right before you call your long-running process, then set it to false when it's complete, either through a callback or in the case of a promise, the `.then()`. If the process is blocking, the state message won't show because the re-render will be blocked until it's done.

Comment: I was wondering as well. where can I do that in the code I provided? Thanks

Comment: Do you have some sample code to share for the promise? Kinda new to all these.

Comment: Again are you saying the code I have above will not work? You did not answer that. Thanks